# How can I create an object in another model based off parent model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having trouble trying to implement (and really map out) a new model object based off a parent model.

The `Bucket` model below has a `category` field based off two `category_options`.

```
class Bucket(models.Model):

    category_options = (
        ('personal', 'Personal'),
        ('social', 'Social'),
    )


    class BucketObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    admin_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='admin_user')
    guest_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='guest_user', blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=category_options)

    ...

    objects = models.Manager()
    bucketobjects = BucketObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.stock_list:
            self.stock_count = len(self.stock_list)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would like to create a new object in a completely different model, `SocialBucket`, when the `Bucket` model instance is selected as a `social` category based off the `category` field above:

```
class SocialBucket(models.Model):
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(Bucket.objects.id, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='social_buckets)
```

**How can I go about populating my `SocialBucket` model with new objects based off it's parent, `Bucket`, model?**

EDIT: As requested, here is the view I would be using:

`view.py`

```
class CreateBucket(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = BucketCreateSerializer
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all()
```

`serializer.py`

```
class BucketCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ('owner','category','name','about')
        read_only_fields = ['owner']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        bucket = Bucket.objects.create(
         owner=user, 
         **validated_data
        )
        bucket.save()
        return bucket
```

Comment: So you want SocialBucket, like a child of Bucket?

Comment: would you provide the view in which you need to implement this.

Comment: @SivaSankar, please see my new edit in the original post :)

Comment: anwered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing models.Model, to Bucket:

```py
class SocialBucket(Bucket)
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(Bucket.objects.id, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='social_buckets)
```

Comment: Hi, this would make a SocialBucket for every object created in Bucket. I only want a SocialBucket object to be created if the ‘category’ social is selected as an option in the original Bucket model.

Comment: Maybe if you have a box in your HTML, that the user himself checks if he wants Social or not, and then pass it in your code to check which type of object to create.

Comment: I actually have that implemented, but I'm looking for help on how to do all the functionality from the backend that creates a new object based on the criteria mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is to use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) signal, for example:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Bucket(models.Model):
    ....

class SocialBucket(models.Model):
     bucket = models.ForeignKey(Bucket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='social_buckets')

@receiver(post_save, sender=Bucket)
def create_social_bucket(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.category == 'social':
        SocialBucket.objects.create(bucket=instance)
```

Also, there is an **alternative way** to implement that. It is to override the save method from Bucket model:

```
class SocialBucket(models.Model):
    bucket = models.ForeignKey('Bucket', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='social_buckets')  # putting the class of model as a string value to avoid import error

class Bucket(models.Model):
    ....

    def create_social_bucket(self, create_social_bucket=False):
       if create_social_bucket:
           Social.objects.create(bucket_id=self.id)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.stock_list:
           self.stock_count = len(self.stock_list)
       create_social_bucket = False
       if self.pk is None and self.category == 'social':
           create_social_bucket = True
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
       self.create_social_bucket(create_social_bucket)
```

Comment: Do you know of any differences between both methods, other than implementation?

Comment: Well, ultimately `save()` method is being called in signal function, so I would say there should not be any performance differences. Its upto your preference. IMHO signal method is cleaner then overriding the save method due to cleaner codes.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not a advised to do. You can hack and hard code:

```
class BucketCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ('owner','category','name','about')
        read_only_fields = ['owner']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        bucket = Bucket.objects.create(
         owner=user, 
         **validated_data
        )
        bucket.save()
        # creating SocialBucket if category is social. You can later update it.
        if bucket.category == 'social':
            social_bucket = SocialBucket()
            social_bucket.bucket = bucket
            social_bucket.save()
        return bucket
```